# translateX causing random border to appear on left side of <div>

Tags: html, css

I am center aligning inline-block elements by using a 50% margin and transformation.

When I add `transform: translateX(-50%);` it causes a thin border to appear on the left side of my divs (its a little hard to see but its on the left of 'all' and left of the 'search products').

[image]

If i try changing the translate to diffrent percentages it stays; sometimes the border gets thicker when i change the percentage. Anyone know why this could be happening?

Here is my code incase i missed something that might be important:

HTML:

```
<div class="tabs">
   <a class="tab active">All</a>
   <a class="tab">New</a>
   <a class="tab">Popular</a>

   <i class="fa fa-search"></i>

   <div class="search-input active">
       <%= text_field_tag :term, params[:term], placeholder: "Search products..." %>
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.tabs {

    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    margin-left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.tabs .tab {

    margin-right: 32px;
    color: #92969c;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 700;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.tabs .tab.active {

    color: #25282c;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 0 #25282c;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 0 #25282c;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #25282c;
}

.search-input {
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 240px;
    padding: 0 32px 0 10px;
    height: 40px;
    position: relative;
}

.search-input input {
    outline: none;
    height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    padding: 0;
}

.search-input.active {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 0 #25282c; 
    box-shadow: 0 2px 0 #25282c;
}
```

**EDIT:** It seems like the issue is happening because of my `box-shadow` code:

```
.search-input.active {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 0 #25282c; 
    box-shadow: 0 2px 0 #25282c;
}
```

But i dont want to have to remove my box shadow to fix this...

Comment: Here is a link to a JSFiddle incase somebody wants to take a look https://jsfiddle.net/d5gbxv1z/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known bug with translate in transforms, and the solution is the [null translation hack](https://aerotwist.com/blog/on-translate3d-and-layer-creation-hacks/):

```
.tabs {

    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    margin-left: 50%;
    translateX(-50%) translate3d(0,0,0);
}
```

By adding `translate3d(0,0,0)` to your element, you can fix your box shadow problem without removing them!

Comment: Thanks, i figured it was a bug but i couldn't figure out what words to google haha, worked perfectly! Thanks everyone else for your solutions too.

Answer (score 1):

**It seems you want it to be a border**

By changing

```
.search-input.active {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 0 #25282c; 
    box-shadow: 0 2px 0 #25282c;
}
```

to

```
.search-input.active {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #25282c;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
}
```

You will get the same result without the faded line on the side.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a shadow to make that border wider, without causing the other tabs to move down, you can add a transparent bottom border to all of them and change its color just on the active one.

Also, you can use [Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) instead of `translate` to horizontally center the menu.

Any of these options alone would fix your problem. Here's an example using both:

```css
.tabs {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.tab {
  margin: 0 16px;
  color: #92969c;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-decoration: none;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-bottom: 4px solid transparent;
}

.tab.active {
    color: #25282c;
    border-bottom-color: #000;
}

.tab:hover {
  border-bottom-color: cyan;
}

.search-input {
  max-width: 240px;
  padding: 0 32px 0 16px;
  height: 40px;
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 4px solid transparent;
}

.search-input.active {
  border-bottom-color: #000;
}

.search-input input {
  outline: none;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 12px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="tabs">
  <a class="tab active">All</a>
  <a class="tab">New</a>
  <a class="tab">Popular</a>

  <div class="search-input active">
    <input type="text" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and the ticked solution didn't helped me so I used margin-left 100% - a couple of percentage for this to work

Before

`transform: translateX(100%); top: 0; right: 0;`

After

`top: 0; margin-left: 97%;`

and this worked for me

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).